# Gulp 4 error: "Did you forget to signal async completion?"

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-sass

I am working on a small project that needs `.sass` files compiled into `.css` files. I have used Gulp a while ago and loved it, but my old `gulpfile.js` does not work anymore, because Gulp has changed since version 4.

I have made a new `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp    = require('gulp'),
    sass    = require('gulp-sass'),
    rename  = require('gulp-rename');

var paths = {
  styles: {
    src: 'src/scss/*.scss',
    dest: 'build/css'
  }
};

function styles() {
  return gulp
    .src(paths.styles.src, {
      sourcemaps: true
    })
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(rename({
      basename: 'main',
      suffix: '.min'
    }))
.pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest));
}

function watch() {
  gulp
    .watch(paths.styles.src, styles);
}

var syncConfig = {
    server: {
      baseDir   : './',
      index     : 'index.html'
    },
    port        : 3000,
    open        : false
  };

  // browser-sync
  function server() {
    init(syncConfig);
  }

var build = gulp.parallel(styles, watch, server);

gulp
  .task(build);
gulp
  .task('default', build);
```

I have a "Did you forget to signal async completion?" error returned by the console.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The functions passed to the gulp.parallel must call a callback once they finnish, see https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/parallel

Comment: @Molda `function server(done) {
        if (browsersync) browsersync.init(syncConfig);
        done();
      }` has the same result, unfortunately.

Comment: What about `watch` and `styles` functions?

Comment: @Molda All the code I gave is in the post.

Comment: Well you said calling `done()` in `server` function results in the same error so i'm asking did you call the callback function `done` in all the functions(styles, watch and server) you are passing to the `gulp.parallel`? Because if not then that's the problem.

Comment: @Molda Yes, I did.

Answer (score 0):

There ware two things missing: the browsersync variable `browsersync = require('browser-sync').create()` and the callback for the server function:

```
function server(done) {
  if (browsersync) browsersync.init(syncConfig);
  done();
}
```

It compiles SASS to CSS, still there is this problem: the page **does not reload automatically** when changes are made in the `main.scss`.

Here is the entire code:

```
var gulp    = require('gulp'),
    browsersync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    sass    = require('gulp-sass'),
    rename  = require('gulp-rename');

var paths = {
  styles: {
    src: 'src/scss/*.scss',
    dest: 'build/css'
  }
};

function styles() {
  return gulp
    .src(paths.styles.src, {
      sourcemaps: true
    })
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(rename({
      basename: 'main',
      suffix: '.min'
    }))
.pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest));
}

function watch() {
  gulp
    .watch(paths.styles.src, styles);
}

var syncConfig = {
    server: {
      baseDir   : './',
      index     : 'index.html'
    },
    port        : 3000,
    open        : false
  };

// browser-sync
function server(done) {
  if (browsersync) browsersync.init(syncConfig);
  done();
}

var build = gulp.parallel(styles, watch, server);

gulp
  .task(build);
gulp
  .task('default', build);
```